# Magento 2.3 png gif image quality are bad

Tags: magento2.3

Magento 2.3 png gif image quality are bad, background not good, popup image very large but original image small

Screenshot
1. Product view page : https://prnt.sc/q6cidb
2. JPG images are good : https://prnt.sc/q6cim6
3. but PNG,GIF files are not showing good : https://prnt.sc/q6cii0

### i can manage image background using css but quality image of png is very bad

### view.xml

```
<media>
    <images module="Magento_Catalog">
        <image id="bundled_product_customization_page" type="thumbnail">
            <width>270</width>
            <height>270</height>
        </image>
        <image id="cart_cross_sell_products" type="thumbnail">
            <width>152</width>
            <height>188</height>
        </image>
        <image id="cart_page_product_thumbnail" type="small_image">
            <width>110</width>
            <height>160</height>
        </image>
        <image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
            <width>240</width>
            <height>300</height>
        </image>
        <image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
            <width>240</width>
            <height>300</height>
        </image>
        <image id="customer_account_my_tags_tag_view" type="small_image">
            <width>100</width>
            <height>100</height>
        </image>
        <image id="customer_account_product_review_page" type="image">
            <width>285</width>
            <height>285</height>
        </image>
        <image id="customer_shared_wishlist" type="small_image">
            <width>113</width>
            <height>113</height>
        </image>
        <image id="gift_messages_checkout_small_image" type="small_image">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>75</height>
        </image>
        <image id="gift_messages_checkout_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
            <width>100</width>
            <height>100</height>
        </image>
        <image id="mini_cart_product_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
            <width>78</width>
            <height>78</height>
        </image>
        <image id="new_products_content_widget_grid" type="small_image">
            <width>240</width>
            <height>300</height>
        </image>
        <image id="new_products_content_widget_list" type="small_image">
            <width>270</width>
            <height>270</height>
        </image>
        <image id="new_products_images_only_widget" type="small_image">
            <width>78</width>
            <height>78</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_base_image" type="image">
            <width>265</width>
            <height>265</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_comparison_list" type="small_image">
            <width>270</width>
            <height>270</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_page_image_large" type="image"/>
        <image id="product_page_image_medium" type="image">
            <width>700</width>
            <height>700</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_page_image_small" type="thumbnail">
            <width>90</width>
            <height>90</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_page_main_image" type="image">
            <width>700</width>
            <height>700</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_page_main_image_default" type="image">
            <width>700</width>
            <height>700</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_page_more_views" type="thumbnail">
            <width>90</width>
            <height>90</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_stock_alert_email_product_image" type="small_image">
            <width>76</width>
            <height>76</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_small_image" type="small_image">
            <width>135</width>
            <height>135</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_thumbnail_image" type="thumbnail">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>75</height>
        </image>
        <image id="recently_compared_products_grid_content_widget" type="small_image">
            <width>240</width>
            <height>300</height>
        </image>
        <image id="recently_compared_products_images_names_widget" type="thumbnail">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>90</height>
        </image>
        <image id="recently_compared_products_images_only_widget" type="thumbnail">
            <width>76</width>
            <height>76</height>
        </image>
        <image id="recently_compared_products_list_content_widget" type="small_image">
            <width>270</width>
            <height>207</height>
        </image>
        <image id="recently_viewed_products_grid_content_widget" type="small_image">
            <width>240</width>
            <height>300</height>
        </image>
        <image id="recently_viewed_products_images_names_widget" type="small_image">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>90</height>
        </image>
        <image id="recently_viewed_products_images_only_widget" type="small_image">
            <width>76</width>
            <height>76</height>
        </image>
        <image id="recently_viewed_products_list_content_widget" type="small_image">
            <width>270</width>
            <height>270</height>
        </image>
        <image id="related_products_list" type="small_image">
            <width>270</width>
            <height>270</height>
        </image>
        <image id="review_page_product_image" type="small_image">
            <width>285</width>
            <height>285</height>
        </image>
        <image id="rss_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>75</height>
        </image>
        <image id="sendfriend_small_image" type="small_image">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>75</height>
        </image>
        <image id="shared_wishlist_email" type="small_image">
            <width>135</width>
            <height>135</height>
        </image>
        <image id="side_column_widget_product_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>90</height>
        </image>
        <image id="upsell_products_list" type="small_image">
            <width>270</width>
            <height>270</height>
        </image>
        <image id="wishlist_sidebar_block" type="thumbnail">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>90</height>
        </image>
        <image id="wishlist_small_image" type="small_image">
            <width>113</width>
            <height>113</height>
        </image>
        <image id="wishlist_thumbnail" type="small_image">
            <width>240</width>
            <height>300</height>
        </image>
    </images>
</media>
```

Comment: Best if you show your view.xml file and custom settings of your theme from backend ( if you have one.)